# Erro no banco de dados: Error Number:1064 no codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

está dando o seguinte erro

> Error Number: 1048
>
> Column 'escala' cannot be null
>
> INSERT INTO `teste` (`escala`, `id`) VALUES (NULL, NULL)
>
> Filename: C:/xampp/htdocs/SAO/system/database/DB_driver.php
>
> Line Number: 691

eu já tentei mudar varias coisas mas o erro continua, meu model está da seguinte forma:

```
class questionariocreate_model extends CI_Model{

    public function quest_create($quest_name){
        $this->load->dbforge();
        $this->db->db_select('resgate');
        $field = array(
        'escala' => array('type' => 'TEXT'),
        'id' => array('type' => 'INT'),
        );

        $this->dbforge->add_field($field);
        $this->dbforge->create_table($quest_name, TRUE);
        //$this->dbforge->add_column($quest_name,$field);

    }
    public function quest_resgate($quest_name,$dados){
        $this->db->db_select('resgates');
        $this->db->insert($quest_name,$dados);
    }
```

}

Meu controller esta da seguinte forma:

```
public function questionario_create(){
    $this -> load-> model('questionariocreate_model');
    $dados['p'] = $this->input->post('questionario');
    $dados['n'] = $this->input->post('n');
    $dados1 = array();
    $dados2 = array();
    $dados3 = array();
    $dados4 = array();

    $this->questionariocreate_model->quest_create($dados['p']); 
    for ($i=0; $i<=sizeof($dados['n']); $i++) { 
            $dados1['escala'] = $this->input->post("escala1_$i");
            $dados1['id'] = $this->input->post("id1_$i");
            $dados2['escala'] = $this->input->post("escala_$i");
            $dados2['id'] = $this->input->post("id_$i");
            $dados3['escala'] = $this->input->post("escala_$i");
            $dados3['id'] = $this->input->post("id_$i");
            $dados4['escala'] = $this->input->post("escala_$i");
            $dados4['id'] = $this->input->post("id_$i");
            $this->questionariocreate_model->quest_resgate($dados['p'],$dados1);
            $this->questionariocreate_model->quest_resgate($dados['p'],$dados2);
            $this->questionariocreate_model->quest_resgate($dados['p'],$dados3);
            $this->questionariocreate_model->quest_resgate($dados['p'],$dados4);
    }
}
```

eu percebi olhando no inspecionar elemento que ele está recebendo os valores do post escala_$i, entretanto esta dando como null na hora de salvar no banco de dados.

e outro problema que estou percebendo é que ele está recebendo todos os valores do meu foreach, sendo que existe um checkbox nele para que eu receba apenas os selecionados, não sei exatamente o por que está ocorrendo esses problemas.

Obrigado a todos.

Comment: Por acaso, o erro não esta aqui? `$dados1['escala'] = $this->input->post("escala1_$i")` esse `escala1$1` não deveria ser `escala$1`?

Comment: eu fiz essa alteração mas agora o erro é o seguinte:

[You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '( `escala` TEXT NOT NULL, `id` INT NOT NULL ) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8 COL' at line 1 ]

Comment: por acaso, esse seu loop não deveria ser algo assim:
          `for ($i=0; $i<=sizeof($dados['n']); $i++) { 
            $dados['escala'] = $this->input->post("escala_$i");
            $dados['id'] = $this->input->post("id_$i");
            $this->questionariocreate_model->quest_resgate($dados['p'],$dados);
      }`